# From an imageview touch point can you resize a MAT to get that points color?

Tags: java, android, opencv, touch-event

In landscape orientation, I using `myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)` and using an `ontouch` listener to `getX` and `getY` and adjust for location of `myImageView` (same as `getRawX` and `getRawY`). I then use `bitmapToMat` to build a MAT to process the image more with OpenCV. I found two resizing scenarios where the `onTouch` location will draw a circle exactly where I touched but at times the location will be outside the Mat and cause a NPE and fail during processing.

Scenario 1: `resize(myImageView.getWidth(), myImageView.getHeight())`

Scenario 2: `resize(myImageView.getHeight(), myImageView.getWidth())` and

```
x = x(myImage.getHeight()/myImageView.getWidth())

y = y(myImage.getWidth()/myImageView.getHeight())
```

If I dont change the x,y I can click everywhere in image w/o the NPE but the circle drawn is nowhere near where I touched.

After processing I `matToBitmap(myMAT, newBitmap)`  and `myImageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap)` .

I am obviously missing something but is there there a simple way to get the touch location and use that location in a MAT? Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of your application. The onTouch callback x and y coordinates are w.r.t ImageView, and if your Bitmap doesn't occupies the full ImageView then you may always get incorrect touch coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

You have to offset the touched coordinates as the view might be bigger or smaller than the mat. Something like this should work

```
private Scalar getColor(View v, MotionEvent event){
    int cols = yourMat.cols();
    int rows = yourMat.rows();

    int xOffset = (v.getWidth() - cols) / 2;
    int yOffset = (v.getHeight() - rows) / 2;

    int x = (int)event.getX() - xOffset;
    int y = (int)event.getY() - yOffset;

  Point  touchedPoint    = new Point(x,y);

  Rect   touchedRect = new Rect();

    touchedRect.x = (x>4) ? x-4 : 0;
    touchedRect.y = (y>4) ? y-4 : 0;

    touchedRect.width = (x+4 < cols) ? x + 4 - touchedRect.x : cols - touchedRect.x;
    touchedRect.height = (y+4 < rows) ? y + 4 - touchedRect.y : rows - touchedRect.y;

    Mat touchedRegionRgba = yourMat.submat(touchedRect);

    Scalar mBlobColor = Core.mean(touchedRegionRgba);

    touchedRegionRgba.release();

    return mBlobColor;
}
```